# konakart installation with mysql database

Tags: mysql, jdbc, konakart

This is very first time I am trying to install konakart in my system. I have jre 6 and konakart 7.2.0.0 and mysql 5.1.32. 
When I start to install konakart each and every thing is working fine then I gave the database name which I already created then proceed, connection with mysql db is ok but finally I got error which I copied here, I am not getting what is wrong because my two friends already installed and it is working fine but it creates problem for me.

nfig' doesn't exist

---

**
* KONAKART LICENSE AGREEMENT
 *
* You may not use this software except in compliance with the licenses.
 *
* Please study the licenses on the KonaKart website  for the rights, obligations
 *
* and limitations governing the use of this software.
 *
* For users of the Community Edition of KonaKart see:
 *
*         http://www.konakart.com/documents/COMMUNITY-LICENSE.txt
 *
* For users of the Enterprise Extensions of KonaKart see:
 *
*         http://www.konakart.com/documents/ENTERPRISE-LICENSE.txt
 *

---

**
KonaKart V7.2.0.0-C0 (-) built 8:57AM 6-Mar-2014 GMT [DB: null]

```
org.apache.torque.TorqueException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxEr
rorException: Table 'konakartdb.configuration' doesn't exist
        at org.apache.torque.util.ExceptionMapperImpl.toTorqueException(Unknown
Source)
        at com.konakart.db.KKBasePeer.doSelect(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.db.KKBasePeer.doSelect(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.ConfigurationMgr.checkIfReturnable(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.ConfigurationMgr.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)20-M
ar 23:55:03 ERROR (?:run:?) com.konakart.al.KKAppException: com.konakart.app.KKE
xception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.konakart.al.KKAppEng.init(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.al.KKAppEng.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.al.ConfigCacheUpdater.getClientEng(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.al.ConfigCacheUpdater.setCheckInterval(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.al.ConfigCacheUpdater.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.konakart.app.KKException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetExcep
tion
        at com.konakart.app.KKEng.manageThrowable(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.app.KKEng.getDefaultLanguage(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.app.KKEng.getDefaultLanguage(Unknown Source)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
orAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.konakart.bl.MgrFactory.instantiateLangMgr(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.MgrFactory.getLangMgr(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.torque.TorqueException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.My
SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'konakartdb.configuration' doesn't exist
        at org.apache.torque.util.ExceptionMapperImpl.toTorqueException(Unknown
Source)
        at com.konakart.db.KKBasePeer.doSelect(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.db.KKBasePeer.doSelect(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.ConfigurationMgr.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.LanguageMgr.fetchDefaultLanguage(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.LanguageMgr.refreshConfigs(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.LanguageMgr.<init>(Unknown Source)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'kon
akartdb.configuration' doesn't exist
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
orAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.ja
va:2155)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:
2322)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Dele
gatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
        ... 19 more


        at com.konakart.bl.ConfigurationMgr.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.app.KKEng.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.app.KKEng.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.EngineConfigCacheUpdater.setCheckInterval(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at com.konakart.bl.EngineConfigCacheUpdater.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'kon
akartdb.configuration' doesn't exist
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
orAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.ja
va:2155)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:
2322)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Dele
gatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
        ... 9 more
com.konakart.app.KKException: org.apache.torque.TorqueException: com.mysql.jdbc.
exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'konakartdb.configuration' doe
sn't exist
        at com.konakart.bl.ConfigurationMgr.checkIfReturnable(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.ConfigurationMgr.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.ConfigurationMgr.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.app.KKEng.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.app.KKEng.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.EngineConfigCacheUpdater.setCheckInterval(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at com.konakart.bl.EngineConfigCacheUpdater.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.torque.TorqueException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.My
SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'konakartdb.configuration' doesn't exist
        at org.apache.torque.util.ExceptionMapperImpl.toTorqueException(Unknown
Source)
        at com.konakart.db.KKBasePeer.doSelect(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.db.KKBasePeer.doSelect(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'kon
akartdb.configuration' doesn't exist
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
orAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.ja
va:2155)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:
2322)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Dele
gatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
        ... 9 more
com.konakart.app.KKException: org.apache.torque.TorqueException: com.mysql.jdbc.
exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'konakartdb.configuration' doe
sn't exist
        at com.konakart.bl.ConfigurationMgr.checkIfReturnable(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.ConfigurationMgr.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.ConfigurationMgr.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.app.KKEng.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.app.KKEng.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.EngineConfigCacheUpdater.setCheckInterval(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at com.konakart.bl.EngineConfigCacheUpdater.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.torque.TorqueException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.My
SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'konakartdb.configuration' doesn't exist
        at org.apache.torque.util.ExceptionMapperImpl.toTorqueException(Unknown
Source)
        at com.konakart.db.KKBasePeer.doSelect(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.db.KKBasePeer.doSelect(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'kon
akartdb.configuration' doesn't exist
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
orAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.ja
va:2155)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:
2322)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Dele
gatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
        ... 9 more
Mar 20, 2014 11:55:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory konakartadmin
org.apache.torque.TorqueException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxEr
rorException: Table 'konakartdb.configuration' doesn't exist
        at org.apache.torque.util.ExceptionMapperImpl.toTorqueException(Unknown
Source)
        at com.konakart.db.KKBasePeer.doSelect(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.db.KKBasePeer.doSelect(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.ConfigurationMgr.checkIfReturnable(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.ConfigurationMgr.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.ConfigurationMgr.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.app.KKEng.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.app.KKEng.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.EngineConfigCacheUpdater.updateConfigs(Unknown Source
)
        at com.konakart.bl.EngineConfigCacheUpdater.run(Unknown Source)

















        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.ja
va:2155)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:
2322)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Dele
gatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
        ... 9 more
com.konakart.app.KKException: org.apache.torque.TorqueException: com.mysql.jdbc.
exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'konakartdb.configuration' doe
sn't exist
        at com.konakart.bl.ConfigurationMgr.checkIfReturnable(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.ConfigurationMgr.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.ConfigurationMgr.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.app.KKEng.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.app.KKEng.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.EngineConfigCacheUpdater.updateConfigs(Unknown Source
)
        at com.konakart.bl.EngineConfigCacheUpdater.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.torque.TorqueException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.My
SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'konakartdb.configuration' doesn't exist
        at org.apache.torque.util.ExceptionMapperImpl.toTorqueException(Unknown
Source)
        at com.konakart.db.KKBasePeer.doSelect(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.db.KKBasePeer.doSelect(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'kon
akartdb.configuration' doesn't exist
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor29.newInstance(Unknown Source
)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.ja
va:2155)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:
2322)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Dele
gatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
        ... 9 more
20-Mar 23:52:27 ERROR (?:handleException:?) com.konakart.al.KKAppException: Ther
e has been an exception in the ConfigCacheUpdater [7.2.0.0]
        at com.konakart.al.ConfigCacheUpdater.handleException(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.al.ConfigCacheUpdater.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.konakart.app.KKException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetExcep
tion
        at com.konakart.app.KKEng.manageThrowable(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.app.KKEng.getDefaultLanguage(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.app.KKEng.getDefaultLanguage(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.al.KKAppEng.init(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.al.KKAppEng.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.al.ConfigCacheUpdater.getClientEng(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.al.ConfigCacheUpdater.updateConfigs(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor31.newInstance(Unknown Source
)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.konakart.bl.MgrFactory.instantiateLangMgr(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.MgrFactory.getLangMgr(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.torque.TorqueException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.My
SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'konakartdb.configuration' doesn't exist
        at org.apache.torque.util.ExceptionMapperImpl.toTorqueException(Unknown
Source)
        at com.konakart.db.KKBasePeer.doSelect(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.db.KKBasePeer.doSelect(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.ConfigurationMgr.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.LanguageMgr.fetchDefaultLanguage(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.LanguageMgr.refreshConfigs(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.LanguageMgr.<init>(Unknown Source)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'kon
akartdb.configuration' doesn't exist
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor29.newInstance(Unknown Source
)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.ja
va:2155)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:
2322)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Dele
gatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
        ... 18 more

org.apache.torque.TorqueException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxEr
rorException: Table 'konakartdb.configuration' doesn't exist
        at org.apache.torque.util.ExceptionMapperImpl.toTorqueException(Unknown
Source)
        at com.konakart.db.KKBasePeer.doSelect(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.db.KKBasePeer.doSelect(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.ConfigurationMgr.checkIfReturnable(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.ConfigurationMgr.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.ConfigurationMgr.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.app.KKEng.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.app.KKEng.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.EngineConfigCacheUpdater.setCheckInterval(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at com.konakart.bl.EngineConfigCacheUpdater.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'kon
akartdb.configuration' doesn't exist
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor29.newInstance(Unknown Source
)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.ja
va:2155)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:
2322)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Dele
gatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
        ... 9 more
com.konakart.app.KKException: org.apache.torque.TorqueException: com.mysql.jdbc.
exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'konakartdb.configuration' doe
sn't exist
        at com.konakart.bl.ConfigurationMgr.checkIfReturnable(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.ConfigurationMgr.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.ConfigurationMgr.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.app.KKEng.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.app.KKEng.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.EngineConfigCacheUpdater.setCheckInterval(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at com.konakart.bl.EngineConfigCacheUpdater.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.torque.TorqueException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.My
SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'konakartdb.configuration' doesn't exist
        at org.apache.torque.util.ExceptionMapperImpl.toTorqueException(Unknown
Source)
        at com.konakart.db.KKBasePeer.doSelect(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.db.KKBasePeer.doSelect(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'kon
akartdb.configuration' doesn't exist
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor29.newInstance(Unknown Source
)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.ja
va:2155)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:
2322)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Dele
gatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
        ... 9 more
com.konakart.app.KKException: org.apache.torque.TorqueException: com.mysql.jdbc.
exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'konakartdb.configuration' doe
sn't exist
        at com.konakart.bl.ConfigurationMgr.checkIfReturnable(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.ConfigurationMgr.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.ConfigurationMgr.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.app.KKEng.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.app.KKEng.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.EngineConfigCacheUpdater.setCheckInterval(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at com.konakart.bl.EngineConfigCacheUpdater.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.torque.TorqueException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.My
SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'konakartdb.configuration' doesn't exist
        at org.apache.torque.util.ExceptionMapperImpl.toTorqueException(Unknown
Source)
        at com.konakart.db.KKBasePeer.doSelect(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.db.KKBasePeer.doSelect(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'kon
akartdb.configuration' doesn't exist
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor29.newInstance(Unknown Source
)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.ja
va:2155)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:
2322)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Dele
gatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
        ... 9 more
org.apache.torque.TorqueException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxEr
rorException: Table 'konakartdb.configuration' doesn't exist
        at org.apache.torque.util.ExceptionMapperImpl.toTorqueException(Unknown
Source)
        at com.konakart.db.KKBasePeer.doSelect(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.db.KKBasePeer.doSelect(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.ConfigurationMgr.checkIfReturnable(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.ConfigurationMgr.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.ConfigurationMgr.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.app.KKEng.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.app.KKEng.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.konakart.bl.EngineConfigCacheUpdater.updateConfigs(Unknown Source
)
        at com.konakart.bl.EngineConfigCacheUpdater.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'kon
akartdb.configuration' doesn't exist
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor29.newInstance(Unknown Source
)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your konakart install perfectly but the problem with the query execute statement, I don't know the precise reason of this error but at the time of installation your konakart fails to create tables in your database. One of the solution is you can download the .zip file which is present in the download page of konakart inside konakart folder you can see one folder database inside database folder you can folders of specific database and all contains corresponding sql file just executes that specific database queries, may be this will helpful for you.
The second solution that I used is my friend installed konakart and each and every thing is very perfectly in my friend system so I took the database that he used for konakart and then I follow the below steps 
suppose name of backup database (given by my friend) is db.sql
1) I copied db.sql in bin folder of mysql 
2) I open command prompt and enter into the bin folder by command prompt then execute command
mysql -u root -p konakrtdb < db.sql
where konakartdb I will use in my konakart and then start konakart server. 
This perfectly working for me and hope will work for you.